# Stop execution of code in JQuery Dialog like Jquery Confirm

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

[Html Select Tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRRVb.png)

```
<select name="testSelect" id="testSelect" >
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Jquery code :-

```
(function () {
        var previous;

        $("#testSelect").on('focus', function () {                
            previous = $(this).val();
        }).change(function() {                
            var r = confirm("If you change display type, default value fields will get reset !");
            if (r === true) {
                previous = $(this).val();                                      
            } 
            else {
                console.log(previous);
                $(this).val(previous);                 
            }                       
        });
    })();
```

I am using this code to restore the previous selected value if I press No..and its working fine when I use Jquery confirm. Here Jquery confirm stops the execution when I change any value and unless I press Yes or no.

But Now I want to remove Confirm box and Want to use Jquery Dialog box for confirmation. Like this :-

```
$( function() {
var previous;
$("#testSelect").on('focus', function () { 
    previous = $(this).val();
}).change(function(event) {   
            var that = this;                                               
            $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({                  
              resizable: false, height: "auto", width: 400, async: false, modal: true,
              buttons: {
                Yes: function() { 
                  console.log($(that).val());                     
                  previous = $(that).val();
                  $( this ).dialog( "close" );                  
                },
                No: function() {                      
                  $(that).val(previous);
                  $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
              }
            });                
    })
```

} );

But here the problem is .. code gets executed even there is Dialog confirm popup. It doesnot stop like the Jquery confirm box does. I tried many stuff but not working, can anyone please help?

Remember: Everything was working fine in JQuery confirm....but not working in Jquery Dialog...

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: *Jquery confirm* - note that the `confirm()` built-in browser function has *nothing* to do with jquery.  This makes your question very confusing when you keep mentioning *jquery confirm` but only have `confirm()` in your code.

Comment: *code gets executed* - what code?   There's no code in your supplied code that will run before the dialog is shown.   You've already provided Yes/No code - these should only run when user selects yes/no.  Are you referring to the `previous=$(this).val()` or some other code?

Comment: `confirm()` (and `alert()`) are *blocking functions* - they will completely freeze your UI until you close the dialogs.   You cannot replicate a "blocking function" in your own code to have js paused while the user does something as js is single-threaded (so if it's paused then they can't complete the action to unpause it).

Answer (score 0):

You need your code in the jQuery document ready state, so that It will get invoke only when  the page is completed load and will bind your events to #testSelect.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var previous;
    $("#testSelect").on('focus', function () { 
        previous = $(this).val();
    }).change(function(event) {   
                var that = this;                                               
                $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({                  
                  resizable: false, height: "auto", width: 400, async: false, modal: true,
                  buttons: {
                    Yes: function() { 
                      console.log($(that).val());                     
                      previous = $(that).val();
                      $( this ).dialog( "close" );                  
                    },
                    No: function() {                      
                      $(that).val(previous);
                      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                  }
                });                
        })
            
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I updated the code as document ready...but still...when I change something is Select Tag...the value  gets changed and then the Dialog pop ups on screen , it doesnot stop the execution like Confirm

Comment: doc.ready is completely irrelevant to the problem described.  It can solve some problems, but only if the js code is before the html it refers to - if, eg, it's just before `</body>` then there's no need for doc.ready.